# Exception when using a udf function with Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

In Spark version: 2.4.0, I am trying to execute the code below on the given DataFrame:
unfoldedDF:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
movieid:integer
words:array -- element:string
tokens:string

```scala
val tokensWithDf = unfoldedDF.groupBy("tokens").agg(countDistinct("movieid") as "df")
tokensWithDf.show()
```

The new dataframe created is tokensWithDf:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
tokens:string
df:long

On it the following operation is done.

```scala
def findIdf(x : Long) : Double = {scala.math.log10((42306).toDouble/x)}
val sqlfunc = udf(findIdf _)
tokensWithDf.withColumn("idf", sqlfunc(col("df"))).show()
```

It fails with the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2519)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:866)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:865)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:865)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:616)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:48)
```

Comment: what is the full stack trace of error?

Comment: You need to give more information, such as questions, full stack trace, and source code.

Comment: Your code works fine on Spark 2.3.2. Please add more details about the version and the entire stacktrace so the error can be reproduced.

Comment: The full stack trace has been added to the original question. The version of Spark is 2.4.0.

Comment: The code works on Spark 2.4.0. Can you share the entire stacktrace ?